# C++ friend class circular include

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I have this problem:

I have class A which is friend with class B. The class A has a `vector<B>`. But I would like for the class B to be able to access the class A.

```cpp
class A
{
   friend class B;
   static vector<B*> buffer;
}

Class B
{
public:
   B()
   {
      A::buffer.push_back(this);
   }
}
```

Is there some other way how I could automatically add the class B to the vector?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Does A have any purpose other than maintaining `buffer`? If not, then make `buffer` a member of B, and scrap A entirely.

Comment: Have you tried a forward declaration of `B` above `class A`? It looks like this: `class B;` You also need to make it `A::buffer.push_back(this);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry I tried to write just simple demo code in the browser and didn't notice it. It should be fine now.

Comment: @FilipGajdušek There are online compilers that comes in handy when making small programs. It helps so that simple mistakes are caught early: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/8ETevKezG)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is almost working.

- You need to forward declare `B`
- You need to use  `A::buffer.push_back(this);`

```
class B; // forward declaration

class A {
   friend class B;
public:
   static std::vector<B*> buffer;
};

std::vector<B*> A::buffer{};

class B {
    friend class A;
public:
    B();
};

B::B() { A::buffer.push_back(this); }
```